# PHP mailer not sending and no error returns

Tags: php, phpmailer

here is my code, tried a couple of solutions like checking if the process is correct and if it's going where I wanted it too. The path. would appreciate any help what I'm doing wrong. Thanks in advance. So far it's outputting `$messsageForSender` but still not sending.

```
include('code/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
if($return_e == true){
            $todayis = date("l, F j, Y, g:i a") ;
            $subject = "Support Request";

                    $messageForSender = "$todayis [EST]
                        <br />
                        <p>
                        Hi $firstname $lastname,
                        <br /><br />
                        Thank you for your inquiry.
                        <br />
                        One of our experts will get in touch with you very soon.
                        <br />
                        </p>";

                        echo $messageForSender;
                        $mail = new PHPMailer();
                        $mail->IsMail();

                        $mail->AddAddress('test@gmail.com');
                        $mail->Subject = $subject;
                        $mail->IsHTML(true);
                        $mail->From=$markto;
                        $mail->FromName=$markto;
                        $mail->Body = $messageForSender;

                    if(!$mail->Send()){
                        echo "Error sending: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;;
                    }else{
                        echo '<h1>mail is sent</h1>';
                    }
```

Comment: `$mail->From="markto";` should be an email address

Comment: @zzlalani sorry for that suppose to be `$markto` fixed awhile ago. Still not fixed though.

Comment: also tell us the output of `$mail->ErrorInfo;`

Comment: @zzlalani Doesn't output any errors.

Comment: is it going into if or else block?

Comment: @zzlalani It's not going in the if nor the else.

Comment: please add this code at the top of your script `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: and retry and paste the output. also check the php `error_log` what is it saying